# spring authentication manager does not bind user service annotated by @Service

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have UserManager class like this -

```
@Service
public class UserManager implements UserDetailsService {

@Autowired
    UserRepositoryImpl userRepositoryImpl;

@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
User user = userRepositoryImpl.findUserByEmail(email);
        List<GrantedAuthority> authList = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authList.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole().getName()));
        UserDetails userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(email,user.getPassword(),true,true,true,true,authList);
        return userDetails;
}
```

Now application security is -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/Home" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/resources/**" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="permitAll" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Admin/**" access="hasRole('Admin')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Teacher/**" access="hasRole('Teacher')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/Student/**" access="hasRole('Teacher')" />
        <form-login login-page="/Login" authentication-failure-url="/Login?login_error=1" authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/Login" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager"/>
    </authentication-manager>
</beans:beans>
```

In web.xml i have added applicationSecurity.xml as context param like this -

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
            /WEB-INF/application-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
```

The problem is when i run my code its throwing exception 
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'userManager' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userManager' is defined

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'userManager' is defined

the same userManager works fine if i autowire it with controller. As UserManager class is annotated with @Service annotation and even i have enabled annotation driven in my dispatcherServlet.xml like this -

```
<context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.opentutor.controllers"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.opentutor.configs"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.opentutor.managers"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="org.opentutor.repoimpls"/>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
```

It should find userManager bean but it does not. Is there something like its loading authentication manager before it scan for the java configuration. Please help with this error.

Comment: Just fyi, `<context:annotation-config/>` is redundant if you have `<context:component-scan>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifecycle of contexts in a Spring web application is as follows:

1. `ContextLoaderListener` loads and merges contexts from `contextConfigLocation` (either the default or the one specified)
2. `DispatcherServlet` loads the servlet context using the merged context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` as a parent.

The context loaded by `DispatcherServlet` has access to the context loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener`, but not the other way around. Therefore, this bit

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userManager"/>
</authentication-manager>
```

in `/WEB-INF/application-security.xml` doesn't have access to the beans generated by

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.opentutor.managers"/>
```

in `dispatcherServlet.xml`.

Re-design your contexts. Your servlet context should only contain bean definitions that are relevant to the servlet context. The `UserManager` bean (and its related `<component-scan>`) is relevant to the application, not the servlet, so put it in the `applicationContext.xml`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation of contexts in spring application. This really helped and i learned a very important concept. Thanks @Sotirios